# Must I include the TestFlight SDK into my app if I just want to send out a beta test?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, testflight

I found [this tutorial](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) which shows how to build an AdHoc IPA for TestFlight. But there is also the TestFlight SDK and I don't understand if I need this and why I would need this for a simple beta test distribution.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to.  You can upload any proper ipa on their site via this page: https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/builds/add/

If you're having problem with your ipa, they have help here:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

The SDK is only for features like tracking crashes, session reports, etc.  It's quite nice, but by no means required.

Comment: I can confirm this from personal experience. Their ad-hoc distribution works great without installing the SDK.

Comment: The problem then is: How to create a proper IPA? I followed their tutorial but it doesn't mention how to actually create those nasty Ad Hoc Distribution Certificate things. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282810/how-to-configure-a-xcode-project-for-beta-testing-with-testflightapp